# Not giving correct output of external batch script C#

Tags: c#, streamreader

I need the program to give the output of the batch script, and at the moment it's just printing

```
System.IO.StreamReader
```

and it should be printing whatever the batch script says

This is only the part that has to do with starting a new process, the variables like the path to the file are declared and the script itself runs but doesn't show proper output

```
Process Uninstaller = new Process();

Uninstaller.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(uninstalldirectory, BatchProcessFileName);
Uninstaller.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Uninstaller.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Uninstaller.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Uninstaller.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Uninstaller.Start();
StreamReader ReadUninstallerOutput = Uninstaller.StandardOutput;
Uninstaller.Close();
string OutputEnd = ReadUninstallerOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(ReadUninstallerOutput);

ReadUninstallerOutput.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Uninstallation Successful");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
Console.WriteLine(ReadUninstallerOutput);
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine(OutputEnd);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're having the Console write `ReadUninstallerOutput`, which is an object, not the string that has the data you want, and all the method is doing is calling the `ToString` method on that type. Judging from your code, you would want to replace:

```
Console.WriteLine(ReadUninstallerOutput);
```

with:

```
Console.WriteLine(OutputEnd);
```